# How to select an element that has no leading or trailing text nodes?

Tags: css

I experimented with using the `:only-child` pseudo-class but unfortunately this does not seem to consider the text nodes:

```
<style type="text/css">
  div span:only-child {
    color: red;
  }
</style>

<div>
  Test
  <span>This still becomes red :(</span>
</div>

<div>
  <span>This becomes red, as it should!</span>
</div>
<div>
  <span>This does not become red - great!</span>
  <span>This does not become red - great!</span>
</div>
```

I am trying to find a way to detect when a specific element is completely alone within its container element in a situation where I am unable to introduce new classes.

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS?

Comment: Good question, but I think you will have to modify the html to do this.

Comment: I would say you need to use js to implement this

Comment: Frankly, even the W3Group admit that not requiring ALL text to be in a proper text element was a mistake. That would have avoided all these issues. Yeah...JS is needed here. CSS can't select (or ignore) elements that don't exist.

Comment: if you check the DOM nodes (in javascript) of the second div, you will have a Text node, a Span element and another Text node because of the newline chars and indentation. So with javascript, you would need to filter text node with space chars only or use <div><span></span></div> without indentation/new lines.

Comment: And this question has 2 upvotes? Oh my god... I really don't understand the way that people upvote/downvote a question. This is not meritory of upvotes at all.

Comment: Don't *all* your divs have text nodes surrounding your spans? Inter-element whitespace is ignored for many purposes in HTML, but is still considered text nodes in the DOM.

Comment: @Paulie_D I suspected that this would be the case; if somebody writes an answer along these lines then I will accept it. Also a reference to a comment from the W3Group thoughts would be interesting to read. Many thanks

Comment: The W3Group have a few. The "text" thing is in an old revision - https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes?rev=1446405966

Comment: Related, there is an open proposal to add a `::text` or `::text-node` pseudo selector on the CSSWG-drafts repo https://github.com/w3c/csswg-drafts/issues/2208

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to achieve this with CSS?

Unfortunately, not.

Included in an [**old revision**](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes?rev=1446405966) of the CSS Working Group "mistakes" list is missing the idea that..

> No naked text mixing with elements. All raw text should have an addressable, stylable element wrapping it, created by CSS if necessary.

[**Current list**](https://wiki.csswg.org/ideas/mistakes)

Text Nodes are not element and CSS can't select (or ignore) elements that don't exist.

So, it's probably best practice to always use a text element when incorporating text in a page...you never know when you might need to style it.

Answer (score 0):

```
div:nth-child(2) span {
color: red;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/cmckay/8663aLcg/